# Access class scope from within anon function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

```
export default class A extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
           items: Items
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged: (r1,r2) => r1 !== r2
        });

        this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.items);
    }

    _renderRow(rowData) {
        return (
            <View key = { rowData.id } >
                <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={ () => console.log(this.state) }>
                    { Registry.render(rowData) }
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

I am trying to console log the state of the class from within anonymous function and I get undefined. Do I have to bind the scopes? I tried with no success.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `=>` lambda function to provide lexical binding of this. Change the code of your function as below:

```
_renderRow = (rowData) => {
    return (
        <View key = { rowData.id } >
            <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={ () => console.log(this.state) }>
                { Registry.render(rowData) }
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
}
```